# Using cloud-init to write_files to ~/.ssh/ breaks SSH to EC2 instance (perhaps any machine)

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, cloud-init

I'm using a Cloudformation template in YAML with an embedded cloud-init UserData to set hostname and install packages and so on, and I've found that once I include the `write_files` directive it will break the default SSH key on the EC2 instance i.e. it seems to interfer with whatever process AWS uses to manage `authorized_files`, in EC2 logs I can see fingerprints of random keys be generating, not the expected keypair.

```
      #cloud-config
      hostname: ${InstanceHostname}
      fqdn: ${InstanceHostname}.${PublicDomainName}
      manage_etc_hosts: true
      package_update: true
      package_upgrade: true
      packages:
        - build-essential
        - git
      write_files:
      - path: /home/ubuntu/.ssh/config
        permissions: '0600'
        owner: "ubuntu:ubuntu"
        content: |
          Host github.com
              IdentityFile ~/.ssh/git
          Host *.int.${PublicDomainName}
              IdentityFile ~/.ssh/default
              User ubuntu
      power_state:
        timeout: 120
        message: Rebooting to ensure hostname has stuck correctly
        mode: reboot
```

Removing the write_files block works fine, leave it in and I cannot SSH to the host due to ssh key mismatch.

So is it due writing a file to `~/.ssh`, maybe `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` gets deleted? Or maybe the permissions on the directory are changed?

Appending to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` with `runcmd` works fine, but I'd like to use the proper `write_files` method for larger files

Comment: I have the same problem here, I can't create new users also

Answer (score 1):

For AWS EC2 Linux instances, the SSH public key from your keypair is stored in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys. If you overwrite it with something else, make sure that you understand the implications.

The correct procedure is to append public keys from keypairs to authorized_keys AND set the correct file permissions.

If you are setting up a set of keypairs in authorized_keys, this is OK also. Make sure that you are formatting the file correctly with public keys and setting the file permissions correctly.

**The file permissions should be 644 so that the SSH server can read them.**

Another possible issue is that when you change authorized_keys you also need to restart the SSH server but I do see that you are rebooting the server which removes that problem.

Ubuntu example:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

Comment: Modifying `authorized_keys` works fine, via both runcmd piping and native cloud-config feature for adding keys, just using write_files to write a file to `~/.ssh/` breaks the SSH config. I'm thinking it may be due to ordering, according to cloud-init docs write_files happens early on, perhaps AWS's authorized_keys mgmt code checks if `~/.ssh` exists after this and assumes SSH is configured, hence no keys added to authorized_keys